# Server not displaying messages from client(JAVA)

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am sending a message :

```
            newbie:hi
```

The text appears on the Server console=>the server receives it but when I echo back,in order to print the same message to my textclient console it doesn't show up this is my code for the echo and below you can also see the code from the TextClient:(what am I doing wrong?it should normally display the message I sent from the TextClient)The method getAll() returns a string with the message and the sender.

```
    public void serverEcho() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectin = new ObjectInputStream(_Socket
                    .getInputStream());
            Message newmess = (Message) objectin.readObject();
            System.out.println(newmess.getAll());
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is the TextClient:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TextClient {
    public TextClient() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException, ConnectException, InterruptedException {

        Socket _socket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        System.out.println("Please enter your desired username:");
        Scanner _new = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _inputname = _new.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Success.You can now type your messages!");
        ClientPeer _clientpeer = new ClientPeer(_inputname, _socket);
        Scanner _scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String _input = _scan.nextLine();

        while (true) {

            if (!_input.equals("exit")) {
                if (_input.startsWith("/w"))
                    _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input, "username");
                else {
                    _clientpeer.sendMessage(_input);
                    _clientpeer.serverEcho();
                }

            } else
                break;

            _input = _scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

ClientPeer class:

```
                     import java.net.*;
       import java.io.*;

  public class ClientPeer{

String _username;
static Socket _Socket;

public ClientPeer(String _username, Socket _Socket)

{
    this._username = _username;
    this._Socket = _Socket;
}

public void sendMessage(String _message) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _Socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
    _obj.flush();

}

public void sendMessage(String _message, String _receiver)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _Socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new PrivateMessage(_username, _message, _receiver));
    _obj.flush();
}
    public static void serverEcho()
    {
       try{ ObjectInputStream objectin=new ObjectInputStream(_Socket.getInputStream());
        Message newmess=(Message)objectin.readObject();
        System.out.println(newmess.getAll());

    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

  }
```

ServerPeer Class:

```
  import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class ServerPeer {
   Socket _socket;

  public ServerPeer(Socket _socket) {
    this._socket = _socket;
  }

  public void methodCall() throws IOException, UnknownHostException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
    Message _message;
    while (_socket.isConnected()) {
        _message = (Message) _ois.readObject();
        System.out.println( _message.getAll());

        _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());

    }
}
   }
```

Comment: `}catch(IOException e){}` - NEVER DO THIS, because *you won't know what went wrong*. At the very least, `}catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}` so you can see the error. (And the same with `ClassNotFoundException`, and any other exception, of course)

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: @immibis  added than you.

Comment: @atishshimpi there are no errors.It just doesn't display the message back on the TextClient.

Comment: @nnewbie Are there errors now that you made your program print errors instead of completely ignoring them?

Comment: @immibis no,no errors.

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block

Comment: where do you actually send anything from server to client?

Comment: @Ubica I believe I do so in the serverEcho() method.Which I then call in TextClient.

Comment: No you don't... You need to put some data on the "wire" towards the client.

Comment: Post every code which is referenced from your code. How is `ClientPeer` initialized? What is the code of `sendMessage()`? Where does it actually access the socket? Everything you use which is not in the standard libraries, you should post. And if it's too long, trim it to the minimum that produces the problem.

Comment: Where is `serverEcho();` method located? on Client or Server? And does your server fail to show messages from client, or the client doesn't show the messages from server? You are very unclear about the problem...

Comment: updates done.@Ubica it is located in ClientPeer.

Comment: Your server never sends anything, so you can't receive anything... The same way you sendMessage from client to server, you need to sendMessage from server to client... It's that easy :)

Comment: @Ubica I thought that what I sent via sendMessage() to the socket ,remains there and I just need to collect it.Sorry ,I am still new to sockets.

Comment: well, imagine both server and client with `input` and `output` of their own, which are connected through the socket `serverOutput --> clientInput` and `clientOutput --> serverInput`

Comment: @Ubica thanks,now I need to call sendMessage() after I receive the message on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void sendMessage(String _message) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
    _obj.flush();
}
```

I would add this method to server and make an if statement for when the server receives a message... `if(messageIsReceived)sendMessage(messageReceived);`